# Why is there an infinite loop when reading a list of integers from a single line using Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need the user to enter a list of integers in a single line, so I wrote this:

```
public static Integer[] readIntegers()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    do list.add(input.nextInt());
    while(input.hasNextInt());
    return list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
}
```

but it keeps looping forever! Doesn't `hasNextInt()` supposed to return `false` if there are no digits on the scanner? How can I fix the previous method? Or should I use `nextLine()` instead and spilt the String?

Comment: Look like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794281/java-infinite-loop-using-scanner-in-hasnextint

Comment: DId you feed EOF into stdin? [ctrl+z in windows, ctrl+d in linux]

Comment: Won't `ctrl+z` finish the whole program?

Comment: p.s. with all the respect to spartan programming, I believe most find `do ... while();` unreadable without explicit scoping, or is it just me? :\

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: It will in linux. In windows it will feed EOF into stdin.

Comment: Why not simply do a `String#split(" ")` and then parse the array contents?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Seems that the most right solution, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.in` does not "end" because you press enter. 
If you want to do it this way, you could probably check for `'\n'` in the `while` expression.

Generally, I would prefer to do it in another way:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = br.readLine();  // line == null indicates end of input.
```

or using `java.io.Console`.

Also, if you use do/while instead of while you might get problems if the input is empty.

Comment: Nice answer.  Do you need to specify an encoding for `InputStreamReader`?  I assume `System.in` already has an encoding associated with it because it's a `PrintStream`, but `InputStreamReader` probably won't pick up on that.

Answer (score 1):

I Believe you just didn't put [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) to your stdin, so your program is waiting for next input..

To feed `EOF`, use `ctrl+z` on windows or `ctrl+d` on linux.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: You are feeding input to your method from command line. The command line is just like a long file, and it keeps reading until it encounters EOF. Just feed [manually, the same way you feed numbers...] EOF to your stdin.

Comment: Well, I got this exception when I tried ctrl+z on eclipse (windows) `java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Scanner throws "NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted" see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Your code assumes there is always at least one integer. If you uses a while loop, it would allow for no values.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you just read a single line and put its contents in a `Scanner`. This way, the user wouldn't have to put in an EOF, but rather just press enter.

Also, you want a `while` loop instead of a `do...while`, because it might be that no numbers are entered. Since the `do...while` first checks the condition after one iteration, your code attempts to read at least one integer, even if there aren't any.