# How do I check to see if the input is an integer?

Tags: java, loops, input, integer

Very Frustrated at my professor, because she did not teach *try* and *catch* concepts, neither did she teach us about *throw exceptions* either, so it is very difficult for me to do this program. **The objective is to make a program where the user is asked to input an integer that prints "Hello World" that many times of the integer.** The problem is I cannot check to make sure the user input is an integer. For instance, if the user chose to type a *character* or a *double*, how do I implement that into my code? And I cannot use **throw exceptions or try and catch** because we did not learn them yet.Thanks guys!!!

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintHelloWorld
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int number;

      System.out.println("Please enter an integer that shows the " + 
      "number of times to print \"Hello World\" : ");
      //store count
      number = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Your integer is " + number);
      int remainder = number%1;
      int counts = 0;

      if( number>0 && remainder == 0)
      {
         while(counts <= number)
         {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
            counts++;
            }
       }
       else
       System.out.print("Wrong, choose an integer!");

           }
         }
```

Comment: Honestly, if your class is still at the point of inputting an integer and doing a simple loop, it makes sense that your professor hasn't taught you exception handling yet.  I would suggest that your professor probably knows what she's doing, and she will be introducing exception handling in a later lesson.

Comment: She will, but I just feel it is frustrating when she gives us an assignment that would gladly need exception handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scan.hasNextInt()
```

will check to see if the next value in the input stream is an integer.

as such:

```
int number = -1;

System.out.println("Please enter an integer that shows the " + 
  "number of times to print \"Hello World\" : ");
//store count
if (scan.hasNextInt()) number = scan.nextInt();

if (number != -1) System.out.print("Your integer is " + number);
```

Comment: Note that this might introduce unexpected behavior with non-ints due to [the blocking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794281/java-infinite-loop-using-scanner-in-hasnextint).

Comment: I got an incompatible types error because it is a .hasNext is a boolean expression, not an integer expression.

Comment: @PatGreens Read the documentation. _has_ means that it check _if_ there's an int. To read the int, use `next` or `nextInt`

Comment: then write $ if (scan.hasNextInt()) number = scan.nextInt();

Comment: So I type this under my  number = scan.nextInt(); ?

Comment: then I write your if statement underneath?

Comment: include the assignment of the value to number inside the if statement with hasNextInt();

Comment: see changes to answer, which shouldn't give you the boolean error.

Comment: Oh ok, now the only problem I have now is that number in **System.out.print("Your integer is " + number);** may not have been initialized

Comment: I still do not understand.

Comment: can initialize the number to a value it won't be.

Comment: The torment is over. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop and validate the input with a regex, like this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = null;
while (true) {
    input = scan.nextLine();
    if (input.matches("\\d+")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter an integer!");
}
int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

This will keep asking for input until a valid integer is entered.

Answer (score 1):

> And I cannot use throw exceptions or try and catch because we did not
>   learn them yet.

For a first attempt, you could create a method that accepts a String as parameter. You will loop through all the chars of this String and check if each char is a digit. While this method returns `false`, re-ask the user for a new input.

Then use `Integer.valueOf` to get the `int` value..

```
public static boolean isNumber(String input)
```

1. You will have to use `sc.nextLine()` to get the input
2. The method [`Character.isDigit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) and [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) will be useful

Comment: I cannot use classes in this assignment, forgot to mention it, not your fault :(

Comment: `Scanner` is a class ! ;)

Comment: I know but she said this is a simple program, so we cant use static classes and that stuff. We learned scanner haha, she is super picky.